# Xamarin.iOS custom cell not showing labels from Interface Builder

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I created 2 custom UITableViewCell's in Interface builder and when I dequeue the cells, they are acting as Default cells. I have 2 sections, the first section should be the header labels and they are not connected to any code so I don't need to change their values (set in IB). Second section will contain multiple rows and be connected to data, so I need to set each labels value.

A few things to note:

- I have double checked that the re-use Identifier is correct in the interface as well as in code
- And finally, I have registered the the cells like so:

`tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(TableInfoDataCell), TableInfoDataCell.cellID);`

**Some code:**

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    try
    {
        switch (indexPath.Section)
        {
            case 1: // Situaltional Data
            { 
                tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(TableInfoDataCell), TableInfoDataCell.cellID);
                TableInfoDataCell cell = (TableInfoDataCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(TableInfoDataCell.cellID, indexPath);
                if (cell == null) { cell = new TableInfoDataCell(TableInfoDataCell.cellID); }
                //cell.SetSuccessCriteria = "N";
                cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
                cell.TextLabel.Text = "Data Cell";
                return cell;
            }
            default: // Header Cells
            {
                tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(TableInfoHeaderCell), TableInfoHeaderCell.cellID);
                TableInfoHeaderCell cell = (TableInfoHeaderCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(TableInfoHeaderCell.cellID, indexPath);
                if (cell == null) { cell = new TableInfoHeaderCell(TableInfoHeaderCell.cellID); }
                cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
                cell.TextLabel.Text = "Header Cell";
                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**What the table looks like when ran, versus what it should look like (based on Interface Builder design):**

[image] [image]

**Custom UITableViewCell class**

Both header and data cells are pretty much identical at this point since neither of them will display when loading the tableview.

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you mean the `TableInfoDataCell`(which is a customed cell) not shows data when running? You could share its `class` property of storyboard and its `.cs` code here.

Comment: The labels on the custom view do not show, so I cannot connect any data to them. I will update the question.

Comment: Okey, do you set `Identifier` for Custom TableViewCell in **StoryBoard**, and keep the same with `TableInfoDataCell.cellID` used in `GetCell` method? You also could share a sample project link here, I will check that in local site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my **StoryBoard** contains with a UITableView and insert a custom TabelViewCell(**StudentCell**):

[image]

**First**, you need to check the `Identifier` is setted in StoryBoard:

[image]

**Then** make sure using the same Cell Id in `GetCell` method:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = (StudentCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell_ID", indexPath);
    var student = Students[indexPath.Row];
    cell.UpdateCell(student);
    //cell.TextLabel.Text = student.FullName;
    return cell;
}
```

**Last**, the custom cell code could modify as follows:

```
public partial class StudentCell : UITableViewCell
{
    protected StudentCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    internal void UpdateCell(Student student)
    {
        //LabelOne/LabelTwo/LabelThree is declared from TabeleViewCell in storyboard 

        LabelOne.Text = student.FullName;
        LabelTwo.Text = student.Course;
        LabelThree.Text = student.Duration;
    }
}
```

You not need to add **AwakeFromNib** method.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That was killing me! `protected StudentCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)` I believe fixed it!